# Twitter Premium API-How we can implement Pagination (next_token and counts)in twitter premium API using python?

Tags: python, twitter

How we can implement Pagination (next_token and counts)in twitter premium API using python in below code?

```
from searchtweets import load_credentials
from searchtweets import gen_rule_payload 
from searchtweets import ResultStream

premium_search_args = load_credentials("twitter_keys.yaml",
                                   yaml_key="search_tweets_premium_api",
                                   env_overwrite=False)


query = "Laptop" 

rule = gen_rule_payload(query, results_per_call=500, from_date="2021-06-01", to_date="2021-06-15")`     
    
rs = ResultStream(rule_payload=rule,
              max_results=500,
              **premium_search_args) 
print(rs)
```